# How do I permanently set bluetooth device as default in pipewire

Tags: firefox, bluetooth, defaults, pipewire

I am running latest Pipewire and I have a Bluetooth headset connected to it.

What I'd like to achieve is that when I turn on my headset, all applications in the laptop start using the microphone profile that shows up in the device. Above all I am interested in getting this to work with conferencing applications such as google meet.

I have configured Pipewire with autoswitch so when I turn on the headphones and some application "requests" microphone usage, it immediately switches to the HFP profile.

However Google Meet still defaults to the laptops internal microphone requiring me to switch every time.

I have already configured the Bluetooth headset profile to be the default one in pavucontrol but it doesn't seem to help much.

My guess here is that because the microphone device only appears once the HFP profile is selected, this does not happen before Google meet (or the browser) has time to select a device to be used.

Is there any way to overcome this?